# Detect Enter Key C#

Tags: c#, keydown, textchanged

I have the following code which does not show the MessageBox when enter/return is pressed.

For any other key(i.e. letters/numbers) the MessageBox shows False.

```
private void cbServer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (enterPressed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter pressed");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("False");
}

private void cbServer_Keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        enterPressed = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Enter presssed: " + enterPressed);

    }
    else
        enterPressed = false;
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: Above code, I thought the issue was with the _Keydown even so I only posted that.

Comment: How does the message box show false. I don't see it

Comment: Also. Have you tried debugging? You should use OEMReturn or what it is also

Comment: What kind of control is cbServer? a combobox? and is a wpf or winforms app?

Comment: What control is the event handler attached to?  cbServer?  Try attaching it to the form instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> `TextChanged` event won't fire.

Answer (score 12):

in your form designer class (formname.designer.cs) add this :

```
this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.Login_KeyPress);
```

and add this code to backbone code (formname.cs):

```
void Login_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            MessageBox.Show("ENTER has been pressed!");
        else if (e.KeyChar == (char)27)
            this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: it also handle Escape key to close your form, I think it is may be useful

Comment: this.cbServer.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.cbServer_KeyPress); This was already in the designer.cs file...

Comment: Sorry I see that is using Keypress not KeyDown.. Will try using that, thanks

Comment: just for completeness, you can type "if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)"  which I think looks nicer

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed");
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Space key pressed");
            }
}
```

Use PreviewKeyDown event to detect any key before shown in textbox or input

Comment: unable to find an "e.Key" option in PreviewKeyDown

Answer (score 0):

```
void cbServer_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {

        // Check if User Presses Enter
        if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Return)
        {
            // Here: user pressed ENTER key

        }
        else
        {
            // Here: user did not press ENTER key
        }
    }
```