# How to know which Enter key pressed in C# winform？

Tags: c#

When we use a keyboard which has two Enter-keys, and their keycode are both 13, how do we know which was pressed?

Comment: To help you research one is actually the *return* key, the other the *enter* key.

Comment: You would need to give us more information about your application for us to answer this. Techniques will vary between console, WPF, WinForms, asp.net applications. Some links here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984238/detect-enter-key-c-sharp  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What @Bathsheba says is correct for the Macintosh and possibly other platforms, but Windows does *not* make a distinction between Enter and Return. The two keys are the same, and the Windows User Experience Guidelines explicitly state that the two keys should have identical command functionality. So, the answer to your question is, you don't!

Comment: Methinks you could still do some low level stuff with the keyboard scan codes: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you Sir,It's a C# application,Now my function is when I press the bigger Enter key then create a newline , and the Small one commit my request,

Comment: public class KeyFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int VK_RETURN = 13;
    private Form parent;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                if (VK_RETURN != ((int)m.WParam & 0xff)) return false;
                if (!(parent.ActiveControl is TextBox)) return false;
                if (((int)m.LParam & 0x1000000) != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("小键盘回车");
                }
}